# LINQ version of calculating sum product of adjacent elements in an array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am looking for a way to do the following in LINQ (it is basically a sumproduct where the same array contains both operands of the product at `n` and `n + 1` indices, obviously the array length is always `2 * n`).

```
int[] input = { -3, 26, -2, 19, 2, 19, 3, 29, 1, 48 };

// sum product
double result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2)
     result += input[i] * input[i + 1];

// result = 57

// linq version of calculating resultPrice ???
```

How can I do this (elegantly) with LINQ?

Comment: Is this real duplicate ?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, how is that a duplicate?

Comment: @haim770 It wasn't.

Comment: LINQ isn't good for everything. This is one of the cases where it isn't. In general, if you have to work with indexes then don't use LINQ.

Comment: @xanatos LINQ is fine here, look at my answer it's pretty self explanatory.

Comment: @TamirVered "self explanatory" like the math demonstrations in my college math books :-) (I still remember sentences like "In few and simple passages omitted for brevity...")

Comment: @TamirVered You call this Zip. Where, Batch, Aggregate mixture self explanatory? Especially compared to 3 the liner crystal clear `loop` in the original post. Hmm...

Comment: @IvanStoev Think about it, you don't care about the indices, You want to take every two items (`Batch`es of 2) multiply them (`Fold`) and add the results (`Sum`), it feels more natural than `2*i+1` (Which is also fine i guess)...

Answer (score 8):

You can [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) the 2 sub-arrays using multiplications and then [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) them, just as you would explain the request:

```
int result = input.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0)
    .Zip(input.Skip(1).Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0), (x, y) => x * y)
    .Sum();
```

---

If you have [`MoreLinq`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) referenced you can have a cleaner solution by folding every batch of 2 items into their product and using [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var res2 = input.Batch(2)
    .Select(z => z.Fold((x, y) => x * y))
    .Sum();
```

Or a more generic solution by using [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Fold`:

```
var res2 = input
    .Batch(2)
    .Select(batch => batch.Aggregate(1, (x, y) => x * y))
    .Sum();
```

Comment: All solutions on this page except for your `Batch` solution are not better than the for loop. +1

Comment: I'd use `.Batch(2).Select(batch => batch[0] * batch[1])` and away with that nasty aggregation. Of course, this is less general now.

Comment: @usr `Batch` returns an `IEnumerable` which means it has no indexer... Thats what the `Fold` is for.

Comment: Ah, right. I'm used to my own "Batch" version that returns an IList for convenience. I have a 2nd version that's fully lazy for rare occasions. Often, the *point* of Batch usage is to get down to a size that is manageable in-memory. That's why the IList usage most often works out.

Comment: @usr Maybe it's worth adding an IList version to `MoreLinq`.

Answer (score 8):

```
 var result = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length/2)
                          .Select(i => input[i*2] * input[i*2 + 1]).Sum();
```

This should be enough. Here example in [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m2nDqw).

---

This code is pretty much mirror of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length/2; i++)
     result += input[i*2] * input[i*2 + 1];
```

which is doing the exact same thing as your loop, but instead of step `+2` of your loop you have step `+1` and loop duration `ArrayItems/2` and you make sum of elements from `input[i*2] * input[i*2 + 1]`

Comment: or just `Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length / 2).Sum(i => input[i * 2] * input[i * 2 + 1]);`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the overload of `Select` that includes the index, then group on the index divided by 2.  Aggregate the values by multiplying them, and finally do a sum.

```
int[] input = { -3, 26, -2, 19, 2, 19, 3, 29, 1, 48 };

var result = input.Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2, x => x.Value)
    .Select(g => g.Aggregate(1, (v, a) => a *= v))
    .Sum();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This will also work for more general cases where you want to sum the produce of n consecutive numbers by dividing by n instead of 2.

Comment: With your LINQ-hammer you were perfectly able to screw the problem :-)

Comment: @xanatos Maybe you can explain exactly how this doesn't answer the OP's question then.

Comment: It is perfect in its horribleness... I gave you a +1 for this reason. It is the question that is wrong, not the answers :-)

Comment: @xanatos I guess it was the person that up voted your comment that down voted the answer then.  Next time I'll also include a Regular Expression solution just in case ;-)

Comment: I'd love to see a RegEx solution to this.

Comment: Congratulations!  You [saved the princess](https://toggl.com/programming-princess)!

Comment: @afrazier I'm no Jon Skeet.

Comment: @juharr True, but that query is an impressive use (or abuse, depending on who one asks) of LINQ!

Answer (score 1):

I am going for the short and confusing version:

```
int result = input.Select((e, i) => (i & 1) * e * input[i & -2]).Sum();    // 57
```