# How to multiply numbers from list?

Tags: c#

I want to multiply numbers in my list but don't know how to solve that problem. My code works, well numbers are in the list except for numbers which are less ore equal to zero. I write a produkt (engl, product) variable but don't have an idea where and how to use it. User stop program pressing number 0 and then pop-up a message produkt brojeva je: (engl. product of numbers is:) and then should multiply numbers from the list. Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vjezba11_kolokvij1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int broj;

            List<int> produktBrojeva = new List<int>();

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unesite broj: ");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out broj);

                if (broj <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Krivi unos.");
                }
                else
                {
                    produktBrojeva.Add(broj);
                }
            } while (broj != 0);
            Console.WriteLine();

            int produkt;

            for (int i = 0; i < produktBrojeva.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(produktBrojeva[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework. You classname is "Exercise11 Colloquium1".

Comment: More prepare for exam but you can look from that corner.

Comment: how come there is no * in your code ? And what do you multiply your numbers with ? With itself ? With a given factor ? Should it become a scalar ?

Comment: You should check the result of `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out broj);` if `broj` contains a valid output.

Comment: no no... numbers on that list multiply, for example, you enter 4 numbers and you stop it and program multiply numbers that are in that list

Comment: You mean, if you enter 3, 4, 5, 0  => you should calculate `3 * 4 * 5` and the result 60 should be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this solves your problem. It's basically your code and i made some minor changes. Although it works, I recommend to use the calculation described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59769548/6077257).

Another Option would be to use Linq for calculation [Multiply up Values from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145297/linq-version-of-calculating-sum-product-of-adjacent-elements-in-an-array)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int broj;

        List<int> produktBrojeva = new List<int>();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unesite broj: ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out broj);

            if (broj <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Krivi unos.");
            }
            else
            {
                produktBrojeva.Add(broj);
            }
        } while (broj != 0);
        Console.WriteLine();

        //Initialize with 1
        int produkt = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < produktBrojeva.Count; i++)
        {
            //Calculate Product
            produkt *= produktBrojeva[i];

            Console.WriteLine(produktBrojeva[i]);
        }

        //Write Product to Console
        Console.WriteLine($"Product {produkt}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With what do you want to multiply you numbers? Basically everything is there. You create your list and loop through your list, you just need to multipy.

EDIT: You seem to want to multiply every number with each other. So:

```
        int produkt = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < produktBrojeva.Count; i++)
        {
            produkt *= produktBrojeva[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(produkt);
```

You need to check for an overflow. produkt can become quite large. maybe you want to use a long instead of an int.

Comment: Doesn't work, it just shows me the numbers which I enter and that's all... it doesn't show me a product of numbers.

Comment: Of course, because produkt was initialized with 1 -- x * 1 = x

Comment: Well, it's multiplied by 1, so the numbers don't change, of course.  What exactly do you want?  A Product is just a result of a multiplication...

Comment: Yes I know, but I wanted to show a product of numbers which are they in list, well depends on how much numbers user enter and which numbers he entered.

Comment: I edited my solution. this is probably what you want to do

Answer (score 2):

Your display loop should be something like:

```
int produkt = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < produktBrojeva.Count; i++)
{
    produkt = produkt * produktBrojeva[i];
}                

Console.WriteLine(produkt);
```

Or better would be:

```
// start with "nothing"
int? produkt = null;

for (int i = 0; i < produktBrojeva.Count; i++)
{
    // if we already assigned the first value, we multiply it.
    if(produkt.HasValue)
        produkt = produkt.Value * produktBrojeva[i];
    else
        // there wasn't a value set, just set the first value.
        produkt = produktBrojeva[i];
}                

// only display the produkt, when it has a value.
if(produkt.HasValue)
    Console.WriteLine(produkt.Value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("There isn't a value");
```

---

Some notes about your code:

```
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out broj);
```

You should check the result of the TryParse, because it returns a boolean if the string could be parsed. If you enter an A, it will output a `0` in broj. But it wasn't a zero.

```
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out broj))
{
    // rest of the code.

}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
```

Comment: I try first code before I go write a question here, it shows me that product is 1 all the time, which can't be if I enter 4, 5 and 6 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:

```
var produkt = produktBrojeva.Aggregate((a, x) => a * x);
```

or if the collection may be empty:

```
var produkt = produktBrojeva.Aggregate(0, (a, x) => a * x);
```

Do not forget to add a `using System.Linq;`

Comment: _"and then should multiply numbers from the list."_  multiply.

Comment: Great, I think it's a nice way, but slightly above the level of the questioner. Don't forget you get an exception when the `produktBrojeva` collection is empty. So you need to check the element count first.

Comment: Thank you all, I find a solution, but won't find without you, you all help me a lot.